# How to gracefully handle SecurityException when an Intent is started?

Tags: android, android-intent

A few users complained that suddenly the couldn't access certain screens. They showed me the screen shot of this exception:

> Stack trace:   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.outlet.UpdateStockActivity}:
> java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10222 does not have
> android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or
> android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION.

This is weird because ecah time the app is started, a dialog asking for location permission will appear if such permission isn't granted before. At least the bug consistently appears
if the location permission isn't allowed (while running the app, I go to Permission Manager -> Location -> remove the app from "Allowed only while in use").

Is it possible to gracefully handle SecurityException so the app doesn't immediately crash?
I tried this:

```
class UpdateStockActivity implements BaseActivity {
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // do DB queyr using current location
        }
        catch (SecurityException se){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please allow location permission first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Various logics involving LocationManager are done inside BaseActivity.

Still crashes, though.

Comment: Why not just...check for the permission and request it if it isn't granted?

Comment: I just updated my question. Adding a `try - catch` to handle `SecurityException` inside BaseActivity seems like a much simpler approach. On the other side, checking permission before `startActivity` seems more tedious

Comment: How is checking if the permission is granted any more complicated than a `try-catch`? You could just use something as simple as `if( !hasRequiredPermissions() ) { showToast(); return; }` (or better yet, request permission) [`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission`](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)? If the app is still crashing with the `try-catch`, add the stack trace. Is something later in the activity lifecycle causing the crash?